# emergency, acra with google spreadsheets

Tags: android, acra

I have to decide tomorrow how to do with my crash reports, as too many reports are saved in my spreadsheets. And I don't wanna switch to bugsense or sth. else, because I'm not ready to pay for it? Is there some tricks (like google script) to auto save each reports in a limit of 1000? Or is there some free reports storage service?

Comment: Bugsense has a free tier for up to 500 errors/month.

Comment: Yes, but it is not fit to me, I need 5K/mon at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheapest way would be to send the reports to a PHP script that would write the useful data to a database (this is supported by ACRA via HTTP POST queries).

You can host this script on a free or cheap shared hosting provider.

Of course this demands some implementation on the server side, but there are some basic scripts you can use on ACRA page.